# @mention autocomplete on nested objects

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, mention

I'm looking to do some really complex autocomplete in a textarea kind of like what occurs with libraries like @mention. I'd like to have autocomplete options start after a delimiter, and then continue after periods to quickly navigate object trees. For example, typing @ would give an autocomplete menu to all the keys in an object, then after selecting that key, the next period starts an new autocomplete that is an autocomplete for all the keys specific to that previously selected object. If the top level object had 3 different layers, the below would be the end result of the final autocomplete.

@[key1.key2.key3]

'@[this.category.UnitPrice]'

'@[topKey.midKey.finalKey]'

Anyone ever run into this kind of situation?

Comment: I have tried only simple autocomplete using http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/ maybe you can customize the option to suit your need.

Comment: [angular-tribute](https://github.com/zurb/angular-tribute) is a @mention engine that might work.